# TypeError: db.getAsync is not a function (sqlite3 at discord.js v14)

Tags: discord, discord.js, better-sqlite3, discord-buttons

so im trying to create a `discord.js v14` code that will work with `better-sqlite3` module and once a button is clicked it will check at db, if he already pressed this button (without clicking the offline as well) and the rest of the code is easily undertandable. Can you help me resolve the error ?

The Error Message is:

```
TypeError: db.get is not a function
at Object.execute (C:\Users\MariosWRLD\Desktop\Programming\New\src\events\interactionCreate.js:21:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

The code is:

```
const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(config.on_duty_role);
                const member = interaction.member;
                await member.roles.add(role);

                const status = await db.get(`time_${interaction.guild.id}_${interaction.user.id}`);
                if (status) {
                    interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [
                            new EmbedBuilder({
                                "description": "** Η κατάσταση σου είναι ήδη ενεργή **",
                                "color": "#ffb600",
                                "author": {
                                    "name": interaction.user.username,
                                    "url": "https://discord.com/users/" + interaction.user.id,
                                    "icon_url": interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()
                                }
                            })
                        ],
                        ephemeral: true
                    });
                } else {
                    interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [
                            new EmbedBuilder({
                                "description": "** Η κατάσταση σου είναι ενεργή **",
                                "color": "#ffb600",
                                "author": {
                                    "name": interaction.user.username,
                                    "url": "https://discord.com/users/" + interaction.user.id,
                                    "icon_url": interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()
                                }
                            })
                        ],
                        ephemeral: true
                    });

                    await db.set(`time_${interaction.guild.id}_${interaction.user.id}`, new Date().getTime());
                }
```

Comment: How did you define `db`? Do other db functions work?

Comment: @Elitezen i have defined it this way:
```const sqlite = require('better-sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite('json.sqlite');```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? A simple search for the library's usage shows a different way of initializing a DB instance : https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3